# Issue with running JavaFX on M1 Pro on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, apple-m1, efxclipse

Whenever I try to run my first and simple *hello world* JavaFX project on my 14 inch MacBook M1 Pro  I see the following screen:

[image: Java folder]

It seems a folder named java, only thing i can do is terminate the process from the eclipse console.

Here more images about the javaFX setup (seems all correct):
I read a lot of different forums and they said that with the latest versione I should have all the libraries in the "Modulepath", however i tried all the different possibilities and no one seems work.

[image: JAVA BUILDPATH LIBRARIES]

a window appears, not a folder

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that illustrates the problem you describe; please, [no images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/230513). See also [_Getting Started with JavaFX_](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) in the [tag:javafx] tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Did you follow the example [in the documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse)?

Comment: Don’t catch the exception in start, just throw it.  If an exception occurs, for example the style sheet resource isn’t found, before you show a stage, the app will just keep running without showing anything as it only shuts down automically when the last stage is closed. The default error handling prints the exception so ack trace to the console anyway, but will also allow the app to exit.

Comment: The Java folder icon you see in the dock is just the default app icon for any java app.  It indicates that your app is running.  To customize the icon, you need to create an installer for your app with a custom icon using a tool like jpackage, which is difficult and non-trivial and not a task recommended for a beginner. So just stick with the default folder icon and don’t worry about it.

Comment: Note that a professional app might catch an exception during start and display a custom alert dialog to inform the user that something has gone wrong, however for a HelloWorld app you don’t want that.  But, do make sure you actually check the console for any errors logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code, without the line about stylesheets.

This code works. A small empty window appears in the middle of my screen.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExEclipse extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage primaryStage )
    {
        try
        {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane ( );
            Scene scene = new Scene ( root , 400 , 400 );
            primaryStage.setScene ( scene );
            primaryStage.show ( );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        launch ( args );
    }
}
```

I used [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) rather than [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)), but that really should not matter.

Though not related to your problem, I suggest adding some content to your pane. For example:

```
root.setCenter ( new Label ( "Hello World! " + Instant.now ( ) ) );
```

I ran this on Apple MacBook Pro, 16-inch, 2021, with Apple M1 Pro chip, macOS Ventura 13.6. Used the *LibericaFX* JDK from BellSoft, version 21.0.1.

My Maven POM file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>PastedFX</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>PastedFX</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>5.10.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0-M3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

More tips, but not related to your problem:

- Learn to use [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) (or Gradle) to manage your dependencies (external libraries) and your build process.
- Install a JDK that includes the JavaFX ([OpenJXF](https://openjfx.io/)) libraries. This is simpler than installing the OpenJFX libraries into your project. At least two of the several JDK vendors provide editions of the JDK offerings bundled with OpenJFX: [Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com/) and [BellSoft](https://bell-sw.com/). Both available conveniently through [*SDKMAN!*](https://sdkman.io/).

Comment: After you say you use IntelliJ I searched for a guide and find this simple one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1v8V7Q90XU . Very helpfull and now all works fine!